# App Service cannot connect to database with Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I have an Azure App Service which I need to grant access to a SQL Database (also in Azure Portal under my account). I want to grant it access via a *Managed Identity*, so I have turned on system assigned Managed Identity.

[image: System assigned managed identity turned on.]

Under Access control (IAM) for the SQL server, I have added the App Service as a contributer.

[image: App Service has been added as contributer]

```
Server=tcp:virtualscorecard.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=GolfScore; Persist Security Info=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=False; Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=False; Connection Timeout=30; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;
```

But when I try to connect, I get the following error in the log stream:

> [Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: An exception occurred
> while iterating over the results of a query for context type
> 'GolfScoreAPI.DbContexts.UserProfileContext'.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.
> The server is not currently configured to accept this token.

I have tried quite a lot of variations in the connection string. The only one that I have gotten to work, is if I add the username and password in the connection string. But Managed Identities should make this unnecessary.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1**

I have been made aware that I need to add my App Service as a user to the database. To do that, I must first assign an Azure Active Directory admin. But I cannot select anything meaningful when I try that. The only entry related to me, cannot be selected because "Microsoft Account members are not allowed."

[image: Microsoft Account members are not allowed.]

**Update 2:**

I got it to work, by creating a group in Azure Active Directory and making myself an member of it. Then setting that group as Azure Active Directory admin on the database, making myself able to add my App Service (`GolfScoreAPI`) as a `dbreader` on the database.

The only thing I still don't get, is why I need to add a firewall rule for the specific IP address. This seems sub-optimal, as that IP address might change (to my knowledge), for instance if the App Service plan is changed.

Comment: You just need to create a db user for the system assigned identity. SQl script: `CREATE USER [<Azure_AD_principal_name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;`. In your case the <Azure_AD_principal_name> is the name of your webapp. Then you can grant specific role on the db" `ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<Azure_AD_principal_name>];`

Comment: To answer last para of update 2 above you can use vnet injection to avoid ip addresses.

1) assuming you have created vnet/subnet...

2) app service > networking > outbound traffic > vnet integration (chose vnet/subnet)

3) sql server > networking > add a virtual network rule  (chose vnet/subnet)

Answer (score 1):

yes important piece is missing. You have enabled the Identity from the App service, what about the SQL server :). You need to add an **Azure Active Directory admin** in sql server. Reference :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-managed-identities-sql

You have already done with Below step.

[image]

Coming to next step for SQL Server.

1. Add a Domain /Individual admin account(registered with AAD) as a SQL server AAD admin. Than follow below steps
2. Login to the SQL server Instance with Login with Authentication type :-  AAD -Universal with MFA
3. Enter the Domain /Individual admin account details, give the password upon login box popup.
   Run the Below Command in the sql server db.
   CREATE USER [<<Identity_name_of_AppService>>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
   ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin/ db_datareader/ db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<<Identity_name_of_AppService>>];
4. Go to the App service & collect the IP address & add in the firewall of sql server to avoid firewall issue.
5. Do the necessary code change in the app service to use the default credential , as shown in image
   [image]
6. Summary of all steps in single place [image]

**Note:-** If you are using Visual studio for development, so while running the Local instance to connect to the Azure SQL, make sure to add your Visual studio subscription Email id as a user.

If you are using the Visual Studio, then make sure

Comment: Couple of questions:
1. What is the `<<Identity_name_of_AppService>>`? - 2. Isn't part of the IM idea, that I don't need IP specifik firewall rules? - 3. What is the `connection.AccessToken` and where do I find it?

Comment: In your case, you dont need to get an access token manually because you're using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` and you configured the connectionstring with `Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity`.

Comment: Yes & <<Identity_name_of_AppService>> is nothing but your app service name. You need to add the Appservice name as db_ddladmin/ db_datareader/ db_datawriter in sql server. so when there will be a call from the App service, Sql server will be aware of the User access. Just like a Normal user,if want to access sql server, so individual account need to get added in sql server or the group name

Comment: In the above screen shot . connection.AccessToken is pinned from the break Point. It will only hold the bearer token that gets created from new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/", _config.TennantId).Result;

Comment: Who do I set as AAD admin? The only one in the list that is related to my account, cannot be selected because: "Microsoft Account members are not allowed."

Comment: I can add mine. can you share the alert? Your User Id should be there in the AAD tenant.

Comment: @lokanathdas I have edited the post with a screenshot, as I cannot add it in comments.

Comment: If you are the tenant owner, can you add another user & try to add that as an admin. I am not the owner so i haven't faced this issue.

Comment: @lokanathdas it's a personal pet project, that's why I'm the owner :-). I think you got me pointed in the right direction. I will update the post when/if I get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: I’ve done all this and it works a treat. However after a few days I get errors with the managed identity auth which can be fixed by disabling then enabling managed identity in the app service followed by dropping the SQL user and recreating. Had anyone seen that at all?